# Retrieve multiple capture group in different order?

Tags: python, regex

Let's have this text:

```
2343 abcd
ajek 4827
1231 skj0
```

And this regex:

```
/(?:(?P<number>\d{4})\s+(?P<text>\w{4})|(?P<text>\w{4})\s+(?P<number>\d{4}))/Jg
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/yN9zK4/1

Where the goal is to retrieve this:

```
{{ number: 2343, text: abcd },
 { number: 4827, text: ajek },
 { number: 1231, text: skj0 }}
```

With [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) and [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) I have no problem to get my regex work.

It seems Python does not offer the `J` option. How can I make it work with Python using other mechanisms than regular expressions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Python re or even regex package to use the same name for different capturing groups.

Comment: Ok I should update my question then

Comment: Other than regular expression, I guess you can use a more generic regex (both tokens `\w+`) to match the string and extract the 2 tokens, then do another test to categorize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through splitting only. This would produce list of dictionaries.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

with open(r'file') as f:
    h = OrderedDict()
    l = []
    for line in f:
        d = {}
        f = line.split()
        for i in f:
            if i.isdigit() and len(i) == 4:
                d['number'] = i
            else:
                d['text'] = i
        l.append(d)

    print(l)
```

Comment: 1 line of Perl against 13 lines of Python. You made my day :(

Answer (score 1):

In your question you write output structure {{a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}}. This structure is impossible, because you can't create set of dictionaries in python. Sets can contain only not changed objects, like numbers, strings or tuples.

You could use list comprehension and simple methods and functions to parse this text into dictionary structure:

```
>>> multiline = '''2343 abcd
... ajek 4827
... 1231 skj0'''
... 
>>> [{'number':y[0],'text':y[1]} for y in (sorted(x.split()) for x in multiline.split('\n'))]
[{'text': 'abcd', 'number': '2343'}, {'text': 'ajek', 'number': '4827'}, {'text': 'skj0', 'number': '1231'}]
>>>
```

Or use linear dictionary generator, like this:

```
>>> {int(k):v for k,v in [sorted(x.split()) for x in multiline.split('\n')]}
{4827: 'ajek', 1231: 'skj0', 2343: 'abcd'}
```